# pyautogui and pydirectinput not working properly on Halo 5?

Tags: python, input, keyboard, mouse, pyautogui

I am trying to write a script in python that would take control of Halo 5 forge in order to automatically create and script an in-game script brain object and use the game's built-in scripting system to script the object to randomize the movement of 2 agents (will be added later) in order to procedurally generate a map, saving me time in doing tedious manual work on creating a method from scratch I have repeated many times in Halo 5 Forge.

Basically I am trying to create a class representing this script brain object in python and under the **init** method it is supposed to follow all of the steps in Forge to create a script brain object.

At first I tried pyautogui as it initially worked previously on Halo 5. But now it doesn't seem to work. It is a known issue that pyautogui doesn't input certain things properly on directX games and was suggested pydirectinput as an alternative.

So I did and while the mouse responds properly in the game and opens the object menu using the press() method, it doesn't actually seem to respond to leftClick() for some reason, only repositioning the mouse to the correct position but not actually clicking the object menu like I had hoped.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import pyautogui as pygui
import pydirectinput as pydi
import time

class forgeObjectRandomizer:
    def __init__(self):
        #CREATE THE SCRIPT BRAIN
        time.sleep(5)
        screenWidth, screenHeight = pydi.size()
        pydi.moveTo(round(screenWidth / 2), round(screenHeight / 2))
        time.sleep(1)
        # pydi.leftClick(1749, 44)
        pydi.press('o')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pydi.leftClick(1554, 337) # --- Extras
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pydi.leftClick(1605, 266) # --- Scripting
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pydi.leftClick(1630, 236) # --- Script Brain
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pydi.press('p') # --- Properties
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pydi.mouseDown(1886, 231) # --- Scroll down
        pydi.moveTo(1886, 453) # --- Scroll down
        pydi.mouseUp()

brainRandomizer = forgeObjectRandomizer()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use to move mouse

```
import win32api,win32con
def click():
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, int(x), int(y), 15, 15)
```

for mouse click equivalent, but I only had problems with moving the mouse

Comment: Its alright, I have no issues with moving the mouse on neither of the modules, its the clicking that I need help with but I already moved on to Halo Infinite Forge so this is a moot point but thanks anyway!